Lifting idempotents of chain complexes
Let $R$ be a (unital, not necessarily commutative) ring and $I \leq R$ a two-sided ideal satisfying $I^2 = 0$ (or more generally $I^n = 0$ for some $n$). It's well known that the ring map $R \to R/I$ lifts idempotents, in that any idempotent of $R/I$ is the residue class of an idempotent of $R$. For any matrix ring $M_n(R)$ the ideal $M_n(I)$ is still nilpotent and $M_n(R)/M_n(I) = M_n(R/I)$, so the result about idempotent lifting applies still. We find that if $P$ is a finite projective right $R$-module then $\operatorname{End}_R(P) \to \operatorname{End}_{R/I}(P/PI)$ lifts idempotents.
Now suppose $X$ is a right-bounded complex of finite projective $R$-modules. Is it true that a (chain-map) idempotent of $X/XI$ lifts if its image is either (1) contractible or (2) has zero differentials? In either of these cases the complex itself (either contractible or with zero differentials) can be lifted (i.e. is in the image of extension of scalars, which I think but am not sure is not true for every complex)
